# Render layers not appearing in the compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

I am trying to follow the Kenan Proffitt tutorial on YouTube for two point motion tracking but the Foreground and Background layers are not appearing in the compositor.

When I add the video input node and select the video I get a small square in the node with the video.

When I add the two Render Layer nodes (for my two layers) and select my scene I don't get that small preview square - and there is nothing from these layers in my final render.  I also get nothing if I plug the Render Layer node(s) directly into the viewer or composite node.

Picture of nodes without little window:

[image]

#### [Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qua5ebahutejyvi/Green%20screen%20-%20light%20saber%202.0.blend?dl=0)

Comment: have you rendered your scene?

Comment: I think so - I hit F12 and have the Rendered view in the bottom right.  That does not have the layers on it.  I also hit the "Animate" button but that did not have any of the information from render layers in the final video either (it was simply a newly rendered version of my original video).

Comment: Delete the movie from the video editor and then hit F12. Then the render will be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the movie from the video editor and then hit F12. Then the render will be visible.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer.  I would never have found this on my own.  Now working perfectly.

Comment: @BlenderJames Welcome to the site :) If this answer has satisfactorily answered your question, then consider [marking it as accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: unchecking "sequencer" in render tab can do the trick too

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the *Use Nodes* checkbox not being checked. It's at the top left of the screen.

[image: Blender top menu screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Go to compositor screen, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and type rendering layer in search